# In C, how to create and send shell variable?

Tags: c, bash, shell, sh

I would like to get the following result, let me explain, we have a file "test.sh", in which we call a command written in c (mycmd.c), and we assign it an argument. We want it to create a variable whose name is the argument passed and then return the result in the "test.sh" file.

Example :

In the file test.sh, we call our command, we assign as argument the name of the variable to create, then we display the extracted result with an echo.

```
#!/bin/bash

./mycmd myvar

echo "OK : $myvar"
```

In the mycmd.c file, we create a shell variable named myvar (the passed argument), then we assign a value to this variable (myvar = foo), and then we return it to the script "test.sh", who returns so "OK : foo".

It's possible ? Thanks.

Comment: No it's not. Think of the security issues that would be created if a process could modify its parent's environment.

Comment: that said, the program may add stuff in your .bashrc or .profile or else, add have the environment variable set for future shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you request cannot be done.  Every program you run, including shells and subshells, gets its own environment.  By default, the contents of that environment is a copy of that of its parent process, but it is separate and independent.  A process can modify only its own environment, not that of any other process.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest you use `setenv`, but after some thinking and testing, it is in fact not possible to do what you want with an arbitrary compiled program. Process environments are protected, and your program gets a new process and therefore a new environment when it runs.

The best way to do this would be to have your program output some shell commands to run. So if your program were the following

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
      printf("export MYENV=helloworld");
      return 0;
}
```

And you invoked it as `$(./myprogram)`, the result of `echo $MYENV` would be `helloworld`. Tested on Bash with Arch Linux. I know this is not exactly what you want, and may not work for your purposes, but it is the best I know.

Comment: Thanks for the idea !